# Количество слогов в файле

Tags: c

Я написала функцию, которая должна считать количество слов и слогов из текстового файла. Слова считает правильно, а вот слоги не считает вообще. Не понимаю, в чем ошибка, вот отрывок из функции, цикл, в котором считаю:

```
int arr[2] = { 0,0 }; //arr[0] - слова, arr[1] - слоги
while ((symb = getc(f)) != EOF) {
    if (symb == ' ')
        arr[0]++;
    else if ((symb == 'а') || (symb == 'о') || (symb == 'у') ||
        (symb == 'и') || (symb == 'і') || (symb == 'е') ||
        (symb == 'А') || (symb == 'О') || (symb == 'У') ||
        (symb == 'И') || (symb == 'І') || (symb == 'Е'))
        arr[1]++;
}
```

Количество слог так и остается 0, хотя в тексте файла есть гласные буквы. Кодировка файла - ANSI, кодировка символов в программме - windows 1251.

Comment: В какой кодировке файл? В какой кодировке символы в коде вашей программы?

Comment: И в файле, и в программе UTF-8

Comment: И компилятор даже не пишет никаких предупреждений при компиляции?

Comment: Неа, ничего не пишет

Comment: А он должен был бы написать про многознаковую символьную константу. Русские буквы в UTF-8 занимают по два байта, а вы сравниваете по одному байту — из-за неполного сравнения русские символы никогда не будут найдены

Comment: Ага... И как это исправить? На какую кодировку сменить файл?

Comment: Самый простой вариант - на windows-1251. (И файл, и код.)

Comment: Не совсем в этом разбираюсь :D В программе установила локаль chcp 1251, а файл могу сохранить только в кодировках UTF-8, UTF-16 или ANSI. Какая из них мне подойдет?

Comment: Скорее, всего, ANSI-кодировка на вашей системе уже и так настроена на использование windows-1251, так что попробуйте ANSI

Comment: Попробовала, но ничего не изменилось(

Comment: Нужно не локаль ставить, а кодировку консоли. `SetConsoleCP(1251);`

Comment: @AlexGlebe так и сделала: SetConsoleCP(1251); и SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);, но все равно в программе у символа 'о' код 18, а в файле у того же символа код 238